# How to get TFS repo ID from path (w/LibGit2Sharp?)

Tags: git, tfs, libgit2sharp

Pretty simple question; title says it all:

**Is it possible to determine a repository's ID if I know its path using LibGit2Sharp (or possibly some other tool)?**

I've looked through the code and documentation online, but I can't find a straightforward way to do this.

**EDIT:** This may be a TFS Git-specific question. When I download a file from my TFS Git server, the download link has a `repositoryId` query parameter. I would like to programmatically determine this value given the repository name. IS there a way to determine this?

Comment: A repository ID? I'm not familiar with a global repository identifier in git. Are you talking about the commit SHA1 hashes? Or can you provide a command line example of what you're trying to replicate.

Comment: @StevenV oh, okay. maybe it's a TFS Git thing then. Sorry, I'm not very familiar with git in general

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Team Foundation Server, each Git repository is given a unique ID.  This information is purely within Team Foundation Server; Git repositories generally do not have any sort of unique ID themselves.  Therefore, you cannot use a Git client like Git for Windows or LibGit2Sharp to access this information.  Instead, you will need to use the TFS REST API:

> **TFS REST API Documentation for Git repositories**
>   http://www.visualstudio.com/integrate/reference/reference-vso-git-repositories-vsi

Simply using the "Get a list of repositories" API should provide you with a mapping between repository names and IDs.